# Get select box value to use as a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, drop-down-menu

I'm hoping someone can help, I'm a relative newbie to javascript and have the following issue. I have a select box with id "mySelect"

that is populated with the following code -

```
$(document).ready(function(artists){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "bookinglist.xml",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function(artists_list) {
                var select = $('#mySelect');
                var artistsArr = [];
                $(artists_list).find('vw_ADM_BookingListNull[strArtistName]').each(function(){
                    var artists = $(this).attr('strArtistName');
                    if ($.inArray(artists, artistsArr) == -1) {
                        select.append('<option value="'+artists+'">'+artists+'</option>');
                        artistsArr.push(artists);
                        }
                    });
                select.children(":first").text("please make a selection").attr("selected",true);
            }
        });
    });
```

I need to use the selected value as a variable to insert into another piece of code. How do I make a variable from this?

The variable will be used in place of

```
'vw_ADM_BookingListNull[strArtistName="James Zabiela"]'
```

in the following code which populates a table from an xml list.

```
$(document).ready(function(unavailable){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "bookinglist.xml",
            dataType: "xml",
            success:(function(unavail){
                    $(unavail).find('vw_ADM_BookingListNull[strArtistName="James Zabiela"]').each(function() {
                    var venue = $(this).attr('strVenueName');
                    var artist = $(this).attr('strArtistName');
                    var booking_date = $(this).attr('dteEventDate').substr(0,10); //subtr strips date down              
                    if(!(booking_date >= $nowformat && booking_date <= $advformat)){
                        $('<tr style="display:none;"></tr>')
                        }
                    else {
                        $('<tr></tr>').html('<th>'+booking_date+'</th><td>'+artist+'</td>').appendTo('#unavail');
                    }
                    });
                })
            });
        });
```

I need to handle the possible event that a value has not been selected and so the value of the select box will be "please make a selection", which is set as the default value.

So I guess I need to wrap some kind of if statement around the code that creates the table, so as to not display anything if nothing has yet been selected.

Any help would be massively appreciated as deadlines are looming.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be using jQuery, so from the [jQuery Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

`var dropdownValue = $('#mySelect').val();`

Comment: Fantastic. I'll give it a whirl. Thanks for your help. I'm new to this so it's great to be given a helping hand.

Comment: Hi, I've incorporated the variable into my coding, but for some reason when I try to use the variable in the code creating the table it returns an error. I'm thinking it is because the page is encountering the variable before it is declared further down the code, but I'm not 100% can you help? Full code can be found here - www.mrblesid.com/blueprint/table.php

Comment: Not quite. The issue is actually that you are declaring the variable in the function `displayVals()`, so it is not accessible outside that function. There a a few ways around this, the simplest two are 1) create a globally accessible variable and populate it, or 2) simply reuse `$("#mySelect").val()` in place of `$dropdownValue` in the ajax call.